# show key and value of jquery ui "instance" method

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i show all key and value of jQuery instance. I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

html:

```
<input id="a" type="text">
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#a").autocomplete({
       source:["abc","def","ghi"]
    });

    var t="<div class='show'>";
    $.each($("#a").autocomplete( "instance" ),function(key,value){
       t+= key +" = " + value + "</br>";
    });
    t+="</div>";

    $("body").append(t); 
});
```

This error `jquery-1.10.2.js:516 Uncaught Error: no such method 'instance' for autocomplete widget instance`

Comment: use autocomplete source method with callback

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which version of jQuery UI are you using? jQuery UI 1.10 does not include `instance`: https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/autocomplete/

Comment: Try to use higher jquery version like 1.12, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery UI version 1.10.2, it will not include the `instance` method and you would have to fail back to `.data()` call.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#a").autocomplete({
    source: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
  });

  var t = "<div class='show'>";
  $.each($("#a").data("ui-autocomplete"), function(key, value) {
    t += key + " = " + value + "</br>";
  });
  t += "</div>";

  $("body").append(t);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="a" type="text">
```

See more: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/

In the future, you may want to properly tag your posts better, with `jquery-ui` so you can get more specific help.